# Closures in javascript, when are they in effect?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am new to js and I am experimenting with closures. There is something I can't get my head around.
If I write

```
var uniqueInteger = (function() { // Define and invoke
                        var counter = 0; // Private state of function below
                        return function() { return counter++; };
                    }());
```

and I repeatedly call the function as `uniqueInteger()` I obtain 0,1,2,3 and so on. It seems then that `counter` is not destroyed after the function is called. Where is it stored since it is not a global object?

Now, if I slightly change the code and define `uniqueInteger` as

```
var uniqueInteger = (function() { // Define and invoke
                            var counter = 0; // Private state of function below
                            return function() { return counter++; };
                     });
```

and I repeatedly call `uniqueInteger()()` the value which I obtain is constantly 0. How is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is it stored since it is not a global object?

In the scope created by the closure.

> Now, if I slightly change the code … the value which I obtain is constantly 0. How is that possible?

Because every time you call `var counter = 0;` in the second chunk of code, you rerun the expression `var counter = 0;` (you also create a new scope and return a new function which you immediately call because you had `()()`).

In the first chunk of code you ran that function once and assigned its return value to `uniqueInteger`, so the expression that set counter to `0` was only evaluated once.

Comment: and that variable will be a different one with a different function scope